# Same trigger enter tag, but two different actions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have troubles trying to make two different actions on trigger enter, its same name tag so I have no idea how to do it. For example I have ground button which has function, etc on first trigger enter it is disabling rotation of some other object, on second trigger enter it enables rotation back.Tried with bools but its not working well, Im thinking about int, but Im not sure. Thanks for any help, Im new in coding.

Heres the code;

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
{
    var buttonRenderer = button.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    buttonRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
    Rotationplane.isRotated = false;
}
```

EDIT:
@derHugoDont know mate, lost my mind...but finally I managed to do it over the if statements, I have no idea does it effect the performance. Heres code if someone has the same problem. Opening the bottle of whiskey...done for today.

````
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(firstCollisionDone == true)
        {
            firstCollisionAavaliable = false;
            secondCollisionAvaliable = true;
        }

        if(secondCollisionDone == true)
        {
            secondCollisionAvaliable = false;
            firstCollisionAavaliable = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if(firstCollisionAavaliable == true)
            { 
                var buttonRenderer = button.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                buttonRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
                Rotationplane.isRotated = false;
                firstCollision = true;
            }
            if(secondCollisionAvaliable == true)
            {
                var buttonRenderer = button.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                buttonRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.white);
                Rotationplane.isRotated = true;
                secondCollision = true;
            }
        }   
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if(firstCollision == true)
            { 
                firstCollisionDone = true;
                firstCollision = false;
                firstCollisionAavaliable = false;
                secondCollisionDone = false;
            }

            if(secondCollision == true)
            {
                secondCollisionDone = true;
                secondCollision = false;
                secondCollisionAvaliable = false;
                firstCollisionDone = false;
            }

        }

    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I assume the flag you want to change is the `Rotationplane.isRotated`.

You could simply invert it's state like e.g.

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
{
    var buttonRenderer = button.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    buttonRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
    Rotationplane.isRotated = !Rotationplane.isRotated;
}
```

Comment: its not working, it only stops rotation, it doesnt activate it again on second collision..

Comment: Are you sure it is executed the second time? This would everytime invert the current state of `Rotationplane.isRotated` .. I don't see why it shouldn't

Comment: Edited post, mentioned you there.